# For loop in a view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have this code:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SomeProperty, new SelectList(new[] {  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }));
```

And I want to populate the `SelectList` dinamically, not always from 0 to 5. Let's say I have the upper limit saved in a `Session["upperLimit"]` variable. How to create a for loop in the view, so that the `SelectList` will go from 0 to Session`["upperLimit"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the select list in the Controller and pass it to the view instead.
View is for iterating the model. The business logic should be in controller.

However if you still want to do this in view you can do something like the following:

```
@{
    var list = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Session["upperLimit"] + 1));
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SomeProperty, list);
}
```

Comment: A view should not retrieve data. A view should use data that is being passed to it under the form of a view model.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov indeed that's what I suggested in the first paragraph i.e. to not do it in view in first place.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, don't put the upper limit in the `Session`, if you need it in the view, the `Model` is the perfect use case for this. Secondly, the `SelectList` should also be contained in the `Model` really, saves you putting logic in the view and that means you don't even need the `Limit` in the `Model`.

Say your Model has these properties:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public SelectList MyNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller action could do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int upperLimit) //I'm assuming that's where the limit is
{
    var model = new MyModel();

    model.MyNumbers = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, upperLimit + 1));

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.MyNumbers)
```

Comment: +1 for using a view model and removing all data retrieval logic from the view which really is not the correct place to use.